# Error while configuring datatable with json

Tags: jquery, plugins, datatable

I have a table as follow

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My json is

```
[{
"Month": "Jan-2013",
"ID": "asdfa0",
"Comments": "",
"Details": "bla bla blba blablabalbal"
}]
```

and my script is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "Script/ahd.json",
    "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "Month" },
    { "mData": "ID" },
    { "mData": "Comments" },
    { "mData": "Details" }
    ]
});
});
```

After doing so i am getting the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined     jquery.dataTables.js:2649

After little googling i got 1 solution to wrap the json in

```
{
  aaData: 
  [{
"Month": "Jan-2013",
"ID": "asdfa0",
"Comments": "",
"Details": "bla bla blba blablabalbal"
}]
}
```

this is also not working...what is wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading the documentation

your js must be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "Script/ahd.json",
                    "sServerMethod": "POST"
                } );
            } );
```

and the json format must be like this

```
{
  "sEcho": 3,
  "iTotalRecords": 6,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 3,
  "aaData": [
    [
      "A","B","C"
    ],
    [
       "A","B","C"
    ],
    [
        "A","B","C"
    ],
    [
        "A","B","C"
    ],
    [
       "A","B","C"
    ],
    [
       "A","B","C"
    ],
   ]

}
```

Comment: How how am i suppose to archive that? cuz i have the same problem

Comment: can you elaborate your query ?

Comment: Is exactly the same as the question posted, and im receiving the same result: [{"Name":"blabla","LastName":"Blabla"},{etc..},{etc..}]